# ReactJS: checkbox state persists even after re-rendering of Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I've created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1030/)

In this fiddle, initially a list of checkboxes is rendered based on the `props` which are passed to the component.
On clicking the `Re-render` button, the same component is rendered with a different set of `props`.

Now, please follow the below steps-

1. Load the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1030/)
2. Check any of the checkbox (let's say I check the 2nd and 3rd checkbox)
3. Click `Re-render` button

Even after rendering the component with new `props`, the state of checked boxes which you checked remains unchanged (2nd and 3rd are still checked)

Why does it happen?
How can I re-render the component with new set of props such that the state of checkboxes do not persist.

Comment: leo has your question answered but I would encourage you to go at this example in a react philosophy - try to refactor the checkbox into a separate component and then manage the `checked` property using `this.setState`. Using if statements works but is not reacty. Here's a fiddle of this as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1034/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @erik-sn I"ll go with this approach.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Because React's** [diff algorithm](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) **is smart**. The conditions to rerender a new component are:

- either the component has a different key **(Different Keys)**
- or it actually is a different HTML element **(Different Node Types)**

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/ufLyy3vh/

The thing is - **neither condition to rerender your** `input` element **is satisfied, so React really reuses the old** `input`. What I've done is to generate a new `key` for every `input` element on each rerender. React assumes this is a new element because the `key` changes and the `input` gets rerendered with the correct `value`.

---

The `Math.random()` is necessary in order to make sure you generate different keys, it's like: Hey, React, this element has changed - please rerender it.

**However, I would argue against this approach** with different keys, because it is against React's philosophy. Why would you use React if you rerender the same element every single time? That's the core of React - not to rerender when the component is the same. **Instead**, you should use onChange handler to update only the values of your inputs without explicitly rerendering *the whole input component*.

Have a look how to work with React [forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: Correct, the `Math.random()` isn't necessary though?

Comment: why not? value is always the same, try it without random;-)

Comment: The value is changing between the objects in this example - but you may have another example where two checkboxes have the same value/label and without the `Math.random()` they won't update.

Comment: That's true, and indeed `Math.random()` solves that issue. Ignore my commen :)

Comment: @leo Thanks for the detailed explanation! :)
And yes, I'd avoid re-rendering of components and instead follow the approach suggested by erik-sn (comment on my question)

Comment: yes erik-sn's approach is the right one.
very glad to see you happy, we all keep learning;-)

Comment: @leo Yes, right! I wish I could stay connected with developers like you all the time (on any of the social network). Happy coding! :)